# MySQL two tables design with keys

Tags: mysql, database, composite-primary-key

I am designing the faculty and department database which includes id, name, school, college, department and so on..

The script for faculty is

```
CREATE TABLE `faculty` (
  `id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `school` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `college` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='faculty';
```

Data will be

```
1, David, Harvard, College of Engineering, Computer Science
2, John, Harvard, College of Engineering, Computer Science
3, Clare, MIT, College of Law, Law
4, Jim, MIT, College of Science, Computer Science
```

Of course, school, college, dept should be different tables and has a relationship.

But I don't have department code(id) and fixed names of it. Department names could be either "`Computer Science`" or "`Computer Engineering`" depends on the schools. College name is same.

Any easy and effective way for these tables and relationships? I don't think simple auto inclement as department_id  isn't good.

Initially, I think 4 chars of department name + auto inclement number can be a composite key in department.

```
Comp0001
Comp0002
Biol0001
Biol0002
```

Thanks for your comments in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand your data, School, College and Department are connected, right? Because in Harvard (school), the Engineering college is called "College of Engineering", while on MIT, could be called "Engineering College" for example. The Departments on the Engineering College could also be different on both schools. Because of that, I would suggest the following model:

```
Faculty (id (PK), name, dept_id (FK), college_id (FK), school_id (FK), update_date)
Department (id (PK), college_id (PK,FK), school_id (PK,FK), name)
College (id (PK), school_id (PK,FK), name)
School (id (PK), name)
```

And I think there is no reason for not use autoincrement on the ID's, unless you have purpose on refer to smart codes like the ones you have suggested.

Comment: thanks for your comments. So do you think there is no reasons not to use auto inclement as IDs (PK) in Department, College, School ?

Comment: I can't see a good reason for use smart codes like you propose. For SELECT queries, some joins will bring the names. And if you are going to create user interfaces to add or modify data, they will use dropdowns... So, on which situation would you need to type smart codes?

Comment: There is no specific situation that I need to type. So good to go with auto inclement? Right?